# How to give a colour property to top and bottom border line of a row

Tags: html, css, vue.js

[image: Top and bottom border line coloured]

I was wondering how to colour the top and bottom border line of each rows, and disable the sides colour of it, I have attached a pic of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `border-bottom/top` (means border **only** to `top` and `bottom`)

```
td, th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

Learn here:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

**See example:**

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If borders are for a DIV:

```
border-top: 1px solid Green;

border-bottom: 1px solid Green;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
div
{
border-top-color:red;
border-bottom-color:red;
}
```

This will make the colour red,
hope this solves your doubt

Comment: @לבנימלכה sorry about that